# Laravel Intermittent php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in AWS Elasticache Redis

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-elasticache, predis

```
Predis\Connection\ConnectionException: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
failed: Temporary failure in name resolution [tcp://redis-server-of-aws-elasticache-url:6379]
```

My server is experiencing intermittent connection timeout in my laravel app predis connection to Elasticache. Based on sentry, the error happens during artisan scheduler command `schedule:run` which is currently called by cron. My laravel is hosted in an ec2 instance and the only purpose is to send emails. My question is, aside from laravel log what things or where should I check in order to know the reason why this type of error is happening? I already checked aws elasticache and everything looks normal.